# How can I change the Django Admin Static Files url?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm hosting my Django project on my own server, and exactly as the docs say, the Django admin media stop showing up.

The solution is simply to host it yourself, which I'm doing. The problem I'm having is that the url the Django admin is using to try to find them is incorrect. Specifically, Django is looking at

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ceasarb-cfa/admin/css/base.css">
```

when I want it to look at

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ceasarb-cfa/static/admin/css/base.css">
```

My question is, how can I change that path?

Intuitively, I've tried adjust the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` file in `settings.py` (currently set to `/ceasarb-cfa/static/admin`) but fiddling with that value didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Meant to change it to "static/admin".

Comment: I just edited it to make it a bit easier to see the difference

Comment: What are STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL set to in your settings.py? STATIC_URL is probably the relevant one here.

Comment: STATIC_ROOT is `/home/ceasarb/ceasarb_dev/Common-Funding-Application/static` and STATIC_URL is `/ceasarb-cfa/static/`. The static files on the rest of my site are fine, only the admin ones aren't being out. (The rest can be found at "example.com/static/<file>")

Comment: You need to re-start your webserver once you've changed `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to the correct value. Have you?

Comment: Yep, tried that as well with no success. Interestingly, the project works fine on two of my friends computers, only on mine do I lose the css.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your settomgs.py you have:

```
STATIC_URL = "/ceasarb-cfa/"
```

but it should be

```
STATIC_URL = "/ceasarb-cfa/static/".
```

Here's more documentation on that setting:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL

Comment: Nope, that's not it. My STATIC_URL is exactly as you guessed.

Comment: Hmm, well the way the admin constructs paths now is by using the static templatetag.  In the admin it is loaded from contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static but that is just a wrapper for contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles (as long as you have staticfiles in your installed apps).  I would run your site with the dev server and put some print statements in there to see how the path is being constructed.